# Zabbix log file monitoring with regex, trying to copy 2nd and 3rd line

Tags: regex, perl, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am using Zabbix monitoring system.  I need to monitor a log file on a windows server for error messages.  The first line just shows ERR and the next 2 lines then have the time stamp and details of the error.  I need to bring all 3 lines into Zabbix.  Zabbix uses perl regex for this.

Below is the regex I have been playing with.  It can find ERR in the log or it can copy the additional lines but not both.  I think what I need is an if then do statement and can not figure out how to write that.

```
\Q[ERR]\E(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*?)(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*?){2}(.+)

\Q[ERR]\E  -finds ERR in the log file
(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*?)(?:\r\n?|\n)(.*?){2}(.+)
```

-copies the next 2 lines
when I put them together it does not work

> Log file: 2023-03-15 18:14:31.149 -04:00 [ERR]   Exception Time:
> 3/15/2023 6:14:31 PM  Exception Message: Could not find file
> '\XXXXX01\Files\51372\Working.xml'.

Please help.  I been bashing my head against the wall for a week now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all 3 lines without capture groups, where the first line contains  `[ERR]`

```
.*\[ERR]\h*(?:\R.*){2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/muPNsu/1)

Or matching all following lines that contain Exception

```
.*\[ERR]\h*(?:\R.*\bException\b.*){2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSYoFs/1)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.  I really appreciate it.